# Calculating probability when order matters only sometimes

Tags: probability, independence

I can find information on calculating the probability of dependent and independent events, but I'm having trouble synthesizing this information in order to calculate the probability of *both* dependent *and* independent events occurring.

More specifically, I'm trying to determine the probability that some single event happens X times in a row (order doesn't matter here -- they're all the same event), and *only then* one of a handful of other possible events occur.

The first event has a probability of occurring 2% of the time, so I believe the probability of it occurring 3 out of 3 tries is 0.02 ^ 3. Each of the other events have probabilities of occurring 1%, 1%, 0%, and 2% of the time. Thus my original attempt at solving this problem was 0.02 ^ 3 * (0.01 + 0.01 + 0 + 0.02) = 0.000032%. This solution seems to ignore the fact that the final event must happen on the fourth try. How can I account for this?

Comment: This sounds like conditional probability. Count carefully.

Comment: You have presented a somewhat abstract version of the problem. A more concrete version may be helpful,

Comment: @AndréNicolas The concrete version would include lots of tedious details, but the short version is: I am working with a digital slot machine and trying to calculate its payout. One piece of this is determining the payout for matching *only* Wild symbols. In most cases, a set of Wilds followed by some other symbol would be counted as a match for that other symbol, but a handful of symbols do not allow Wild matches and thus the match would be counted as a Wild match instead.